# How to check if a webview is already open in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) of flutter. It has 3 methods, `launch`, `canLaunch`, and `closeWebView`. How can I possibly know if a WebView is already open? Also, there's no callback to know if the WebView got closed by clicking on close by the user.

I need to refresh the page once the WebView is closed. Now, I can't refresh the page if the user closes the WebView by clicking close.

Is there any way I can get to know if a WebView is open? or a callback if the existing one got closed?

Answer (score 0):

simply use a bool value to watch it.

```
bool webviewOpen;

launch().then((){
  webViewIsOpen = true;      
});

 closeWebView().then((){
  webViewIsOpen = false;      
});
```